# Lotus Notes first setup disable popups

Tags: python, windows, powershell, lotus-notes

on windows OS 10/8.1/8/7, how do I disable. how can I disable the program from showing these popups asking for setting lotus notes as default mail program and if i'm sure I want to exit etc... at the first time I run the program. is it possible to do it through the command line? if yest, how? I didn't find any good reference over the web.

Comment: i'm using IBM Notes version 9.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 things to test

[DontCheckDefaultMail=0](http://www.lotus-expert.com/en/notes-ini-reference/2432-dontcheckdefaultmail.html) and probably the [eclipse settings](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd8forum.nsf/0/b61ba0fbb860b1fc852576b600430727?OpenDocument)

Comment: couldn't make it work for IBM Notes Version 9.0.1, can you please show an example of where and how you set it?

Comment: OK, I guess I've found the solution:
at "C:\Users\<USER_NAME>\AppData\Local\IBM\Notes\Data\notes.ini"
append "DontCheckDefaultMail=1" to top of page (below "[Notes]") and under that appen "ExitNotesPrompt=1" to exit without getting a popup (taken from: https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/dominowiki.nsf/dx/list-of-notes.ini-variables-that-roam-and-what-they-control)